# Explicit linear combination of some matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologize in advance for how messy this is, I've never had to use latex.

\begin{matrix} 
10  \\
40 \\
30  \\
20 
\end{matrix}

This is matrix A

\begin{matrix} 
1 \\
2\\
3\\ 
4\\
\end{matrix}

This is matrix B

\begin{matrix} 
1 \\
1\\
1\\ 
1\\
\end{matrix}
This is matrix C

\begin{matrix} 
-9 \\
17\\
-7\\ 
-1\\
\end{matrix}

This is matrix D

How does $A*4(B)*-15(C)=D$ ?

It's an example in my notes that I need to know, and for the life of me I can't figure it out. For more context:

$y_i=\alpha x_i+\beta+\epsilon_i$ for a regression chart, with matrix B being the x values and matrix A being the y values. Matrix D is the values of the $\epsilon$ values. How do we arrive at $\epsilon$?

Comment: [Take a look at this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26447/19169)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually seem to have is $A=4B+15C+D$ except for a transposition in $A$. Perhaps you meant $A-4B-15C=D$?

Comment: Oh that's exactly what it is! Thank you very much, it makes perfect sense too.